# Best practice for saving GCM key ids

Tags: android, sql, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

So, GCM generates different registration ids for different devices. In an normal scenario, a user can have a either one phone/tablet or multiple phones/tablets, each with unique registeration id.

In that case what is the best practice for saving the GCM keys for each device to same user.

Update 1

One way which I have read and people are using is reading, hashing and saving Mac address of the device in database together with the key. This does solve the problem but is this the best solution or there is a better one?

Comment: Whats wrong with a database?

Comment: I do already have them in database, but it gives problem for e.g. if app crashes, user clears all data and login again he will get a new key, now server have two keys which belongs to same user and device. Gcm does notify that key has changed but still sends multiple messages. In order to tackle  these kind of problems. Data table structure should be such that these problems shouldn't occur

Comment: @DuseanSingh What did you go with in the end? Two tables: one for users and one for gcm keys? i.e. a user has many gcm keys?

Comment: @ChristianFazzini, I don´t remember which project that was for? But in latest projects, i have two tables one with keys and one with user. Key table have a unique device id, calculated from device id, mac and other stuff. Device id is unique for every device. When GCM notifies that key is dead, we remove the key. When user logs in, we change owner of the key to newly logged in user. When user logs out, we remove the key. This way we solve most of the problems

Answer (score 1):

You can use [user notifications](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/notifications.html), which allow you to group multiple registration IDs belonging to the same user under a single `notification_key`, and then sending a single message to that key would send it to all the registration IDs connected to it.

The alternative is to send the messages to each registration ID separately.

In both cases you should have a DB that maps a user ID to multiple registration IDs.

Comment: Thanks, in order to get notification key, I am required to have all the registration id's to a particular user. How to save those keys is what I want to know. For e.g. how many columns I am required to have in database

Comment: @DuseanSingh You'll need one column for user ID and one column for registration ID. Since registration ID is long, creating an additional column that hold a hash value of the registration ID can be useful for queries (since you can index that column, while registration ID is too large to index). You might want to introduce an additional column that would identify the device (some random identifier that you assign for each device).